# Angular 2 Interface throwing error of non existing property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular 2 interface **books.ts**

```
export interface Books {
artists: Object;
tracks: Object;
}
```

This is the my service file where I am using it with http request **searchService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Books } from 'app/pages/search-results/books';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

constructor(private _http:Http) { }


 getBook(keyword): Observable<Books[]>{
  return this._http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + keyword + '&type=track,artist')
  .map((response: Response) => <Books[]> response.json());
 }
}
```

And this is my component where I am using interface **searchResults.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchService } from 'app/shared/search/search.service';
import { Books } from 'app/pages/search-results/books';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-search-results',
 templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.css'],
 providers: [SearchService]
 })
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
keyword: any;
sub: any;
books: Books[];
errMessage: string;
arists: Object;

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router,        private _search: SearchService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.sub = this._route
  .queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
    // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
    this.keyword = params['keyword'] || 0;
    this.getBooks(this.keyword);
  });

// 
}

getBooks(value) {
this._search.getBook(value)
  .subscribe(
  res => {
    this.books = res;
    console.log(res.artists);
  },
  error => { this.errMessage = <any>error }
  );
 }

}
```

The error comes when I try to console the **res.artists**. The error says **Property 'artists' does not exist on type 'Books[]'**. I am new to Angular 2 and doesn't know how to fix that.

The response is looks like

```
{artists:{limit: 20, item:[]}, tracks:{limit: 20, item:[]}}
```

Comment: what's the logged data when you  do `console.log(res);`

Comment: @anoop it shows {artists:{limit: 20, item:[]}, tracks:{limit: 20, item:[]}}

Comment: I think commenting the console.log won't solve it for you, since you getting object and you trying to map with `Array<Books>`, try changing it to `this.books = [res];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I am getting Object in response and I am assigning it to an Array which is causing the error. I have simply changes the both types to object and it solved my problem.

From this

```
books: Books[];
```

To this

```
books: Books;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you try to get res.artist from collection of books. You can check it by for or e.g res[0].artist to get concrete artist.

Comment: Maybe try to remove  <Books[]>  before response.json

Answer (score 0):

*getBook* function in class *SearchService* return an array of Books object (Books[])
so, the *res* in getBooks function in *SearchResultsComponent* will be an Array of Books.

You can `console.log(res)` to see detail, if you want access to artists please try with `res[0].artists` if the res is not an empty array